# Accessing a while-loop created array outside of the loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am creating an array using a while loop. (For reasons why I am creating an array this way, go to https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2151.txt) Though once my array (`data`) is created inside the while loop, I cannot access it outside of the while loop. I was hoping to make it so the user could put in the name of a country, say India, and get the number of mobile users in that country.

```
String address = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2151.txt";
URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
Scanner in1 = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
System.out.print("Please enter the name of the country you would like to see the mobile users for: ");
String country = in.next();
 while (in1.hasNextLine()){
 line = in1.nextLine();
 String[] data = line.split("\t");
 if (data[1].contains(country) == true){
   System.out.println("Country name: " + data[1]);
   System.out.println("Mobile phone subscribers: " + data[2]);
   return;
 } 
 else{
   System.out.println("No country found with that name!");
   return;
    }
  }
```

The input works if it is inside the loop, but will only work with China because it is the first country in the list. I understand why it is not working correctly, thought I'm unsure how to fix it other than putting the `if` statement outside of the loop, but if I do that, the statement cannot reach my array. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here :

```
 if (data[1].contains(country) == true){
   System.out.println("Country name: " + data[1]);
   System.out.println("Mobile phone subscribers: " + data[2]);
   return;
 } else {
   System.out.println("No country found with that name!");
   return; //<-----ISSUE
 }
```

When `return` is called in your else clause it terminates the program. What it really needs to do is iterate through the second run of the loop.

Remove the `return` in your `else-statment`.

Here's the revised code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String address = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2151.txt";
        URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        System.out
                .print("Please enter the name of the country you would like to see the mobile users for: ");
        String country = in.next();

        while (in1.hasNextLine()) {
            line = in1.nextLine();
            String[] data = line.split("\t");

            if (data[1].contains(country) == true) {
                System.out.println("Country name: " + data[1]);
                System.out.println("Mobile phone subscribers: " + data[2]);
                return; //<--- will exit after printing ^
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No country found with that name!");
    }
}
```

Here's a sample run: `{input} India`

```
Please enter the name of the country you would like to see the mobile users for: India
Country name: India
Mobile phone subscribers:       893,862,000
```

Comment: 33 seconds and you'll be the answer. Thank you so much for that, I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Agony Not a problem. Took me less than a minute to find the issue with my `debugger`. If you're planning on programming some more in the future I highly recommend you learn to use one.

Comment: I will definitely have to look into it. I've been sitting here for about 3 hours looking at it. I'm nearly bald with the hair I've pulled out :P

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to iterate to second line because you are returning the while after first iteration whether it found the country or not.

I would suggest to remove the `return` statement from the else condition.

I have also used a `boolean` variable found which will be set once the country is found and `No country found` message will be appear only if that country is not in list.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountryName {
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String address = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2151.txt";
    final URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
    final Scanner in1 = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean found = false;
    String line;
    System.out
            .print("Please enter the name of the country you would like to see the mobile users for: ");
    final String country = in.next();
    while (in1.hasNextLine()) {
        line = in1.nextLine();
        final String[] data = line.split("\t");
        if (data[1].contains(country) == true) {
            System.out.println("Country name: " + data[1]);
            System.out.println("Mobile phone subscribers: " + data[2]);
            found = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("No Country Found");
    }
in.close();
in1.close();
}
```

}

On the other note, if you wants to use collections your program will become more concise and easy to read. Here is the same logic with `HashMap`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountryName {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String address = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2151.txt";
        final URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
        final Scanner in1 = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final Map<String, String> countryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (in1.hasNextLine()) {
            final String[] line = in1.nextLine().split("\t");
            countryMap.put(line[1], line[2]);
        }
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the country you would like to see the mobile users for: ");
        final String country = in.next();
        if (countryMap.containsKey(country)) {
            System.out.println("Country Name: " + country);
            System.out.println("Mobile phone subscribers: "+ countryMap.get(country));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Country found with that name");
        }
        in.close();
        in1.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
String[] data;
```

before your loop. That will make its scope greater than just the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Declare data outside "while" but assign it inside.

```
String address = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-        factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2151.txt";
URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
Scanner in1 = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
System.out.print("Please enter the name of the country you would like to see the mobile users for: ");
String country = in.next();
String[] data; 
while (in1.hasNextLine()){
   line = in1.nextLine();
   data = line.split("\t");
   if (data[1].contains(country) == true){
     System.out.println("Country name: " + data[1]);
     System.out.println("Mobile phone subscribers: " + data[2]);
     return;
   } else{
   System.out.println("No country found with that name!");
   return;
   }
 }
Objects.toString(data); // now its visible
```